# How to drag & drop in ViewPager2?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I need to add drag & drop the item event in ViewPager2.
But, I can't find the example of viewPager2 with ItemThouchCallBack.OnItemMoveListener.

I know that RecyclerView can support this event. but because of the design, I have to use ViewPager2.

the Design example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oERL.png)

my code:

```
public class CourseHorizontalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CourseHorizontalAdapter.HorizontalViewHolder> {

    private List<StoreDTO> courseList;
    private ConfirmSuggestedCourseActivity activity;

    public CourseHorizontalAdapter() {
        this.courseList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public CourseHorizontalAdapter(List<StoreDTO> courseList) {
        this.courseList = courseList;
    }

    public List<StoreDTO> getCourseList() {
        return courseList;
    }

    public void setCourseList(List<StoreDTO> courseList) {
        this.courseList = courseList;
    }

    public void setActivity(ConfirmSuggestedCourseActivity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HorizontalViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ItemCourseDetailHorizontalBinding binding = ItemCourseDetailHorizontalBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);
        return new HorizontalViewHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HorizontalViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(courseList.get(position), position);

        holder.itemView.setOutlineProvider(ViewOutlineProvider.BACKGROUND);
        holder.itemView.setClipToOutline(true);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> activity.toPlaceDetailActivity(courseList.get(position)));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return courseList.size();
    }

    public void clearItems() {
        courseList.clear();
    }

    public void addItems(List<StoreDTO> courseList) {
        this.courseList.addAll(courseList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public class HorizontalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ItemCourseDetailHorizontalBinding binding;


        public HorizontalViewHolder(ItemCourseDetailHorizontalBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }

        public void bind(StoreDTO storeDTO, int position) {
            setPref(storeDTO);
            setImageViews(storeDTO);
            setHashTags(storeDTO.getTagList());
            setTime(storeDTO);

            binding.num.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));
            binding.nameTv.setText(storeDTO.getStoreNm());
            binding.addrTv.setText(storeDTO.getAreaDetailNm());
            binding.priceTv.setText(activity.moneyFormat(storeDTO.getReprMenuPrice()) + activity.getString(R.string.store_won));
            binding.btnFindWay.setOnClickListener(v -> activity.goToPlace(position+1, courseList));
        }

        private void setImageViews(StoreDTO storeDTO) {
            String url;
            if (storeDTO.getStoreImageUrlList().size() == 0) {
                url = CommonUtils.createDefaultImageUrl();
            } else {
                url =  storeDTO.getStoreImageUrlList().get(0);
            }
            GlideApp.with(binding.image.getContext()).load(url).into(binding.image);
        }

        private void setPref(StoreDTO storeDTO) {
            String[] prefData = null;
            String storePref = "";
            switch (storeDTO.getPrefSn()) {
                case EAT_PREF_SN:
                    prefData = activity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category_foods);
                    break;
                case DRINK_PREF_SN:
                    prefData = activity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category_drinks);
                    break;
                case PLAY_PREF_SN:
                    prefData = activity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category_plays);
                    break;
                case WATCH_PREF_SN:
                    prefData = activity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category_sees);
                    break;
                case WALK_PREF_SN:
                    prefData = activity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category_walks);
                    break;
            }
            for(int i=0; i<prefData.length; i++) {
                if(storeDTO.getPrefData().charAt(i) != '0')
                    storePref += (prefData[i] + " ");
            }
            binding.subjectTv.setText(storePref);
        }

        private void setHashTags(String tagList) {
            binding.storeTags.removeAllViews();
            if(tagList != null && tagList != "") {
                binding.tagsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                String[] tags = tagList.split(" ");
                for (String tag : tags) {
                    TextView tagView = new TextView(activity.getApplicationContext());
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    layoutParams.leftMargin = 10;
                    tagView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                    String tempTag = "#" + tag;
                    tagView.setText(tempTag);
                    tagView.setTextSize(10);
                    tagView.setPadding(20, 10, 20, 10);

                    tagView.setBackground(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(activity.getResources(), R.drawable.back_gray_50dp, null));
                    binding.storeTags.addView(tagView);
                }
            }
        }

        private void setTime(StoreDTO storeDTO) {
            int time = storeDTO.getStoreCostTm();
            String storeTime;

            if (time > 60 && time%60 == 0)
                storeTime = time/60 + "시간";
            else if (time > 60 && time%60 > 0)
                storeTime = time/60 + "시간 " + time%60 + "분";
            else
                storeTime = time + "분";

            binding.timeTv.setText(storeTime);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to move item with drag & drop.